# How to clear drive space used by Apple Mail App without removing Internet Accounts?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I'm no longer using the Apple Mail app built into OS X and it is consuming 20GB+ of space from old mail. However, I do use Calendars and Messages on those accounts. I unchecked "Mail" on those accounts, but that doesn't clear the space. If I try to remove the Internet Account, it warns that it will delete all my Messages (the Messages App messages), which I don't want to do.

It has been suggested that I simply delete the folder where Mail App stores the messages `~/Library/Mail/V2` and/or `~/Library/Mail/V3`.

Can I safely free up space from mail messages from Mail using this method?

Is there another method to safely do this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Mail stores its stuff by default under ~/Library/Mail/V2 and V3

You can free up space in there. (of course a Time Machine backup would be a good idea before deleting the content of these folders)

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting that I just delete all the contents of these folders after backing up my data? Is this a safe way to free up space?

Comment: SAFE is a bit relative in this context, but it's as safe as any delete operation can be :) You can do a Get Info on the folders and see it there is enough in there to make it worthwhile. You WILL remove those messages from your Mac. Have you looked into Disk Inventory X? It will tell you exactly what is using up space.  http://www.derlien.com/